# How to use both pman and custom help files in Vim with the viewdoc plugin?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

When editing PHP files I want to use help files from two sources:

- vim help files in `/etc/vim/bundle/yii-api-vim/doc/` from [here](https://github.com/mikehaertl/yii-api-vim).
- PHP man pages with `pman`

If there's no help available from the help files it should try `pman`.

The [`viewdoc`](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3893) plugin's help claims that

> You can have several documentation sources for same file type, and choose which one should be used on-the-fly.

But it does not explain, how to do this. The only feature that comes close are handlers for a specific filetype, like `ViewDoc_{filetype}(topic, filetype, synid, have_context)`. But I don't know how to implement such a function.

Open questions to me are:

- How can I check inside that function if a `*.txt` file exists in my specific directory?
- What should I return to let `viewdoc` open such a help file if it exists?
- What should I return to let `viewdoc` open a `pman` page for a ordinary PHP function?

It would be helpful to see an example for such a function.

Comment: What did you try? How did it fail?

Comment: I didn't try anything because a) i'm not confident in vimscript and b) from the manual i wouldn't even know what to return so that it opens my help files in my specific directory.

Comment: You might want to ask for examples on the [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/vim-plugin-viewdoc/issues/list). I Don't think enough people have used this plugin to write an example.

Comment: Link to @MichaelHärtl issue on the tracker https://code.google.com/p/vim-plugin-viewdoc/issues/detail?id=12

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not an expert on vim scripting, so this may not be an ideal solution, but this is what worked for me.

First create a custom viewdoc handler in the *viewdoc_pman.vim* file (which can be found in the *~/.vim/bundle/viewdoc/plugin/* directory if you are using the recommended pathogen installation).

```
function ViewDoc_pman_custom(topic, filetype, synid, ctx)
  let l:tagpath = '/etc/vim/bundle/yii-api-vim/doc/tags'
  let l:shell = printf('grep %s %s', shellescape(a:topic,1), l:tagpath)
  let l:output = system(l:shell)

  if !v:shell_error
    return g:ViewDoc_help(a:topic, a:filetype, a:synid, a:ctx)
  else
    let l:ViewDoc_pman_old = function('ViewDoc_pman')
    return l:ViewDoc_pman_old(a:topic, a:filetype, a:synid, a:ctx)
  endif
endfunction
```

This function uses *grep* to look for the specified *topic* string in the *yii-api-vim* tags file. If it finds it there, it just forwards the command to the default *ViewDoc_help* handler (this is assuming you've already installed the *yii-api-vim* documentation so that it works correctly with the standard help).

If *grep* doesn't find anything, then it falls back to calling the old php handler in the *ViewDoc_pman* function. Note that we can't just call *g:ViewDoc_pman* directly since that is a variable that we are about to overwrite. We need to get a handle to the old function using `function('ViewDoc_pman')` and call that instead.

Finally, you need to find these two lines:

```
let g:ViewDoc_pman = function('ViewDoc_pman')
let g:ViewDoc_php  = function('ViewDoc_pman')
```

And replace them with these two:

```
let g:ViewDoc_pman = function('ViewDoc_pman_custom')
let g:ViewDoc_php  = function('ViewDoc_pman_custom')
```

This  forces all php documentation queries to be forwarded to our new custom handler rather than the old *ViewDoc_pman* function.

If you prefer not to edit the *viewdoc_pman.vim* file, you can put the viewdoc handler in your *.vimrc* file instead. Then to set the *g:ViewDoc_pman* and *g:ViewDoc_php* variables, you'll need to add the following lines:

```
autocmd VimEnter * let g:ViewDoc_pman = function('ViewDoc_pman_custom')
autocmd VimEnter * let g:ViewDoc_php = function('ViewDoc_pman_custom')
```

The `autocmd VimEnter` forces the assignments to happen after all plugins have been loaded, otherwise those variables would just be overwritten by the plugin and your custom handler would never be called.

Comment: Thanks, this solution really works! But it requires to change the plugin files what i want to avoid. According to the help it should also work to create a `ViewDoc_php` function in your `.vimrc` (see [here](https://github.com/powerman/vim-plugin-viewdoc/blob/master/doc/viewdoc.txt#L378)). This didn't work at all for me: Any function in my `.vimrc` was ignored. Did this work for you somehow?

Comment: I did briefly try getting the code to work in .vimrc, but the problem was the need to overwrite the *g:ViewDoc\_php* and *g:ViewDoc\_pman* variables. From what I could tell .vimrc gets loaded before the plugins, so those variables aren't defined yet. But I will do some more investigation and see if I can find a way.

Comment: Also see [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/vim-plugin-viewdoc/issues/detail?id=13).

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying. My computer isn't dealing well with the heat at the moment and it tends to shut itself down every time I start up my Linux VM. However, I've just had a chance to test, and that `autocmd VimEnter` trick you found seems to be solution. I suspect you've already figured that out, but I've updated my answer anyway for future reference. Also, thanks for the bounty!

Comment: Your example should be updated for compatibility with vim-7.4.260, see https://code.google.com/p/vim-plugin-viewdoc/issues/detail?id=26